# Occurence of a element in unsorted array by O(n)

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, find-occurrences

This is driving me nuts:(

Problem statement:

An unsorted array is inputed.Next the user gives a collection of numbers and the program should print the occurrence of the given number in that array.

**This should run at O(n) time complexicity.**

Example:
Input array:[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0]

Collection of numbers:

1

2

1

0

Output:

3

2

3

1

**Constrains:Array can be of size 10^5 and collection of number can be of size 10^5**

P.S:I have made a code with O(n^2)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){
    int *n,size,key,count=0;
    scanf("%d",&size);
    n=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        scanf("%d",&n[i]);
    }
    scanf("%d",&key);
    for(int i=0;i<key;i++){
        count=0;
        int temp=0;
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
            if(temp==n[j])
                 count+=1;
        }
        printf("\n");
        if(count==0){
            printf("NOT PRESENT");
        }
        else{
            printf("%d",count);
        }

    }

    }
```

Any help is welcomed :)

Comment: Let me guess these numbers are actually digits?

Comment: use a dictionary. if you encounter say "3" store 1 under key "3", if you encounter "3" once again, your dictionary should have such value: "3":2 and so on. or you can use array instead of dictionary too.

Comment: Further to what Giorgi wrote above, you can use a hash table to create the dictionary. If the hash table size is significantly larger than the number of elements in the input array (say, twice as large), lookup and insertion/increment should be approximately O(1). Then the overall complexity will be O(max(m,n)) where m is the length of the input array and n is the number of numbers in the collection.

Comment: Does "collection of number can be of size 10^5" imply the range of numbers read is [0 ... 9,999]?  Something else?

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: there are on two valid signatures (regardless of what visual studio might allow) for the `main()` function.  `int main( void )` and `int main( int, char* )`  They all have a returned type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: the variable `size` should have a type of `size_t`, not `int` so it will contain the proper type for the parameter to `malloc()`  suggest: `size_t size;` and `if( 1 != scanf( "%ul", &size ) )`  and because of that fix, this line: `for(int i=0;i<size;i++)` should be: for( size_t i=0; i<size; i++ )` and this line: `for(int j=0;j<size;j++){` should be: `for( size_t j=0; j<size; j++){`

Comment: the posted code calls `scanf()` to input the `key` to search for in the array, so why read yet another value into `temp` then search for that value in the array?  especially using `key` as a loop counter limit value.   The value read into `key` could be anything from -2gig to +2gig,  I.E.  it has no relationship with the number of elements in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make a array of 10^5 and initialize it with 0. Now iterate over array and increment the value in array. Like you encounter a 5 increment arr[5] and now you can answer the queries in O(1) time.

Below is a code in java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
          Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in());
          int n=s.nextInt();
          int arr[]=new int[100001];       //Array is initialized 0 
          for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
          {
               int num=s.nextInt();
               arr[num]++;
          }
          while(s.hasnextInt())
          {
              int p=s.nextInt();
              System.out.println(arr[p]);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: "initialize it with 0." is not clearly shown here in this Java answer to a C post.  At least a comment about where initialization is implied would be helpful.

Comment: edit done. And in the post it was not written user wanted answer in c language he was having problem with the logic behind the problem, so I provided a answer in java.

Comment: rajat188, note that the posted was tagged C.  See [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) "tags appear on the question page, so other people will take them into account when answering your question."

Answer (score 3):

The range of elements is small.  So create an array of counters for the possible values and increment the count for each value you find.  For example, if you find 2, increment `counter[2]`.

Then given your collection of numbers, just do an array lookup to get the count.

Comment: How do we know the range of elements is small?

Comment: Can you clarify how you came to that? The constraint say "Constrains:Array can be of size 10^5 and collection of number can be of size 10^5" that implies the size of the arrays, no?

Comment: @IanAbbott It's a constraint listed in the question: *collection of number can be of size 10^5*

Comment: If I'm misunderstanding the statement couldn't "collection of number can be of size 10^5," refer just to the size of the array and not the value of the elements?

Comment: of *size*, but the numbers themselves are not limited.

Comment: 10^5 is only 100000, which is relatively small.

Comment: What's missing is whether the numbers in the array are constrained in a known range (other than `[INT_MIN .. INT_MAX]`)

Comment: @samanime 10,000 may be small on platforms you use, but is large and significant on common embedded processors in 2017.  IAC, it is an `O()` related issue.

Comment: @chux Yes, if this was being done for an embedded processor. But if it's goal is O(n), then it's going to have to use more memory. With a more constrained array size, the efficiency would have to go up in order to minimize memory use. It's a trade-off. The question clearly states that it's allowing a certain amount of memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity is O(max(m,n)) where m is the size of the array and n is the size of the collection. The space required is O(p) where p is the range of the integers that may appear in the array. We'll use p0 to denote the lower bound of this range.

The solution is simple:

- Construct an array C of size p and set all values to zero
- Walk over the input array and for each value k - increase C[k-p0] by 1. Now you have a count of each value.
- Walk over the collection and for each value k - print C[k-p0]

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this would be to have your resulting array's keys be where the values are.

My C skills are kind of weak, but here is how in pseudo-C (you'll have to tweak it to make it work properly:

```
int size = 10*10*10*10*10;
int[size] input = getInput();
int[size] results = new int[size](0); // fill array with zeros

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if (input[i] === -1)
    break; // assuming -1 signifies the end of the input

  output[input[i]]++; // increment the value at the index that matches the number by one
}

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if (output[i] === 0)
    continue; // number wasn't in array

  printf('%d', output[i]);
}
```

Basically, you put the input of the array in the matching index of output.

So, if your input is `5,3,2,1,1,5,3,2,1`, you would put into output:

```
output[5]++;
output[3]++;
output[2]++;
output[1]++;
output[1]++;
output[5]++;
output[3]++;
output[2]++;
output[1]++;
```

resulting in an array that looks like this:

```
[0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1]
```

Then you just output it, skipping the zeros because they weren't present.

Comment: This solution would be good if we know the range of the elements. 10^5 refer just to the size of the arrays. Though this satisfy O(n) in time-complexity, space-complexity would be horrible if the range of element values were extreme.

Comment: Indeed, but it's highly unlikely that the size of the numbers are larger than the size of the array. While it's not stated in the problem provided, a solution that is still O(n) for any arbitrarily large number would be a problem that is many, many magnitudes more complex then I suspect it's meant to be. I even doubt you could create a true O(n) solution with a fixed memory size with an arbitrarily large number, because you'd have to have some sort of hashing function involved somewhere which would likely be greater than O(1).

Comment: The point of my comment is from a theory standpoint. "Highly unlikely" does not subject itself to impossible under theoretical scrutiny. I myself am nether claiming that I know of a solution that can accomplish this with O(1) memory size, but it is to be that this solution be acknowledged of this memory size situation.